# Find Data Patterns from Database automatically

Tags: database, pattern-matching, data-mining

We want to Extract Data Patterns from Data smartly and automatically.

We have the following Phone Database Struture (Few Fields noted to give example)-

PhoneName(string), LaunchDate(Date), LaunchPrice(Currency), AmoutOfRam(Number), IsTouchScreen(Bit), IsProximitySensor(Bit), IsCompassSensor(Bit)

We have around 1500 phones in database. We want to derive smart rules like-

1. If the launchdate is 2016 and LauchPrice is above 200$ then AmountOfRam will be more than 2GB.
2. If the phone has a TouchScreen than it will definitely have a ProximitySensor.
3. If the launchdate is 2016 and LauchPrice is above 400$ then it will Definitely have a Compass.

Analyzing the data in the database, we want an algorithm to AUTOMATICALLY find these patterns.

Can someone suggest a framework, reliable technique to do this? Any starting point shall help as well.

Regards,
Swapneel Shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time over reading a Data Mining book, and Google search, use BI (Business Intelligence) algorithms with MS SQL server.

Here is the link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175595.aspx

[And there should be parallel solutions with databases as well]

All the basic algorithms are available and can be used with a Quick Configuration Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Discretize the numerical attributes, and use **association rule mining**.

For details, see *any* textbook on data mining. Your question is too brad to be answered in this format - the answer fills a chapter of an introductory book.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually expected this to be a common problem and we should by now have a ready App Dev framework that can do most of the work. Something like Business Intelligence does with SQL server.

Yeah, I am anyway reading a Data Mining Book over the weekend. :)